# pass a javascript variable as a param in url_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm trying to pass a javascript variable into the ruby on rails 「 url_for」method

is that possible??

```
<a href="<%= url_for(:controller => 'epgs', :action => 'show', :parameter1 => myJavaScriptVariable %>" data-inline="true">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, JavaScript variables are not in the scope when your ERB is being rendered as this is being done server-side. Javascript can only be used once the page has been fully rendered by Rails and returned to the user (i.e in the user's browser). If you really need a JavaScript variable in the URL then a simple way to do it would be to add the extra parameter to the href using JavaScript once the page has loaded:

```
  new_link = $('#link').attr('href') + '&parameter_1=' + myJavaScriptVariable;
  $('#link').attr('href', new_link);
```

using jQuery or something similar.

Comment: Quite right! Obviously, the #link element won't be available to replace the href until the DOM is fully loaded. Didn't want to make the response too JS or jQuery heavy, though. :)